# Divisibility by 7 of pascals numbers.

Tags: number-theory

This is more of a discussion question than anything but how do you tell $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is dividable by a prime p. I started playing around with the $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and came to a fairly obvious conclusions about divisibility.

> If  $k\geq p^\alpha$ where $p^\alpha$ is the largest power of p less than n, then $p\nmid \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$(The same conclusion can be drawn for $(n-k)\geq p^\alpha$).

So all that needs to be considers are the $k\in \{a\in Z_n\mid a,(n-a)\geq p^\alpha \}$. But that is about it.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: if n=14, k=9, p=2 then $\alpha=3,9=k\ge p^{\alpha}=8$. but $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = 2002$ is divisible by 2

Comment: Thank you for your comment DavidP. I was assuming all of the factors of of p happened prior to $p^\alpha$ which is a very silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that the exponent $e_p(n!)$ of the prime $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ is given by $$e_p(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{p^k}}\right\rfloor$$